# How to put the comment box at bottom of all widgets in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, blogger

In the mobile view of my website, many important widgets are below of comment box. Now I want to put the comment box at the bottom of all the widgets or just above the footer section. Can you guys give me any suggestions for this?

Here are all the references below.

1. This is my demo/testing website link for the problem **-**  https://demo-site-336.blogspot.com/

[After going to the site click on a post to see the comment box position. Please remember, I am talking about **Mobile View/Mode**. I don't want to change the comment box position of **PC View/Mode**]

2. This is the **XML file** of the site. You can find all the codes used for the site in it. **-** [Click Here For The XML File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yclJvn3au5stHWVkuPKuQ2Y7OGVXavv3/view?usp=sharing)
3. This screenshot will show you the current position of the comment box.
   [image]
4. This screenshot will show you the position where I need the comment box.
   [image]
5. You can use this website to see the Mobile View/Mode of a site. **-** http://mobiletest.me/

I hope these things will help you to solve my problem. If anything more is needed just leave a comment. Thanks from the bottom of my heart for your valuable time. Goodbye.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - post code HERE so we do not have to load all sorts of external sites that will disappear soon

Comment: As I am new here, SO does not allow me to attach screenshot. Anyway thanks dear @mplungjan for your time.

Comment: If you click edit. then click the `[<>]` button, you can make a [mcve]